# why this doesn't show a PDF in explorer?

Tags: html, asp.net, pdf

My intention is show a PDF embeded in an aspx page. I've been triying to embed a pdf inside aspx for a pair of days in order to work with explorer and firefox but for some reason in explorer doesn't work, so my first step was created an html in order to perform tests. My html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Preview</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            border: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>    
    <embed src="sample.pdf" width="500" height="375" type='application/pdf'>
</body>
</html>
```

In explorer doesn't work and firefox works so
What am i mising?

Comment: "explorer" is your shorthand for "Microsoft Internet Explorer"? If so, what version? Are you aware [Microsoft is phasing out Internet Explorer](http://www.techinsider.io/microsoft-phasing-out-internet-explorer-2016-1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

The client must have a plugin in the browser for show the PDF file. If he haven't you can write a message and purpose a download...

```
<object data="sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">

  <p>You have no plugin PDF viewer <a href="sample.pdf">
  download the PDF file.</a></p>

</object>
```